# How can I turn off caching redirect?

Tags: 8, caching, redirection

I have a url that would normally redirect to a specific page, however, some code is run prior to this. I am returning a `RedirectResponse` instance, and it appears to be being cached. How can I force this not to be cached?

Comment: Are you sure Drupal is doing the caching, because browsers will sometimes cache redirects.

Comment: For me, it really was Drupal, as the RedirectResponse uses 302 which browsers shouldn't cache.

Comment: See related: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/278698/disabling-page-cache-for-redirect-response/278703

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A response built from the RedirectReponse class is not cached. So you should not need to set any cache metadata. The problem here is probably the page cache for anonymous requests, which caches all responses, even redirects and no matter if they are cachable or not.

You can disable this cache by using the kill switch before returning the response:

```
\Drupal::service('page_cache_kill_switch')->trigger();
```

This will only disable the *Internal Page Cache*. To control caches outside of drupal, like proxies or browser caches, go to `/admin/config/development/performance` and set a "Page cache maximum age" or set response headers. See this comment [How can I turn off caching redirect?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/222038/how-can-i-turn-off-caching-redirect?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment371445_222038)

Comment: You can try that, but in redirect.module, we explicitly use cacheable redirect responses to have them cached. I think they aren't by default. As the comment from @mpdonadio says, this might actually be the browser doing the caching

Comment: The class name in the question is the original Symfony redirect response without Drupal caching. For the browser cache see my edit.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I was unclear. I meant those responses should actually *not* get cached, because to have them cached in redirect, we need to use a cacheable response.

Comment: @Berdir `RedirectResponseSubscriber` changes ordinary `RedirectResponse` objects to `LocalRedirectResponse` objects which are cacheable.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comments above, `RedirectResponseSubscriber` does alter redirects.  Here's the relevant snippet:

```
if (!($response instanceof SecuredRedirectResponse)) {
    try {
      // SecuredRedirectResponse is an abstract class that requires a
      // concrete implementation. Default to LocalRedirectResponse, which
      // considers only redirects to within the same site as safe.
      $safe_response = LocalRedirectResponse::createFromRedirectResponse($response);
      $safe_response->setRequestContext($this->requestContext);
    }
```

So if you have a custom redirect that should not be cached, then create a custom class that extends `SecuredRedirectResponse` and implement the required `isSafe()` method.  You may wish to leverage `LocalAwareRedirectResponseTrait` to use there to verify the url is local, along with any other check to verify that this is your redirect and not a mis-use.  Your redirect will then skip the block above and not be converted to a cacheable redirect.  Thanks to @smartsheet-eng for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: This is not necessary. When this code is converting a RedirectResponse (not supporting cacheable metadata) it automatically adds a cache max-age of 0. See https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Routing%21CacheableSecuredRedirectResponse.php/function/CacheableSecuredRedirectResponse%3A%3AfromResponse

Answer (score 0):

You may want to cache your response with [CacheableRedirectResponse](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2573923)