# Don't cache custom Front Page domain

Tags: 8, event-subscribers

I'm working on a module that shows a different frontpage per role. I have three frontpages:

1. the base `www.domain.nl` for `anonymous` users, set in the basic site settings
2. for users with `role_1` they go to `sub1.domain.nl\dashboard`
3. for users with `role_2` they go to `sub2.domain.nl\dashboard`

I'm almost there but the frontpage url is set in cache (I think) therefor when I login I get the right frontpage. So I have `role_1` en go to `sub1.domain.nl`. Now when I logout I want to go back to `www.domain.nl` but I still get redirected to `sub1.domain.nl`. Even when I close the browser and return to the site I still get back to `sub1.domain.nl`.

So my question is how can I make sure this response is cleared from cache after loggin out or is not even cached at all? What is the best method to deal with this?

*My code till now:*

**mymodule.services.yml**

```
services:
  mymodule.event_subscriber:
    class: Drupal\mymodule\EventSubscriber\FrontpageSubscriber
    tags:
      - {name: event_subscriber}
```

**src/EventSubscriber/FrontpageSubscriber.php**

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\mymodule\EventSubscriber;

use Drupal\Core\Routing\TrustedRedirectResponse;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;

class FrontpageSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function checkFrontRedirection(GetResponseEvent $event) {
    $current_path = \Drupal::service('path.current')->getPath();
    $front_uri = \Drupal::config('system.site')->get('page.front');
    $front_alias = \Drupal::service('path.alias_manager')->getAliasByPath($front_uri);
    $current_alias = \Drupal::service('path.alias_manager')->getAliasByPath($current_path);
    $isFrontPage = \Drupal::service('path.matcher')->isFrontPage() || $front_alias === $current_alias;

    if ($isFrontPage) {
      $hasRole1 = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load(\Drupal::currentUser()
        ->id())->hasRole('role_1');
      $hasRole2 = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load(\Drupal::currentUser()
        ->id())->hasRole('role_2');

        if ($hasRole1) {
          $domain_url = 'https://sub1.domain.nl/dashboard';
          $response = new TrustedRedirectResponse($domain_url);
          $event->setResponse($response);
        }

        if ($hasRole2) {
          $domain_url = 'https://sub2.domain.nl/dashboard';
          $response = new TrustedRedirectResponse($domain_url);
          $event->setResponse($response);
        }
     }
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
    $events[KernelEvents::REQUEST][] = array('checkFrontRedirection');
    return $events;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could be a caching issue within the browser, Drupal or both. For the browser set cache headers in the response, see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/278703/47547.

For Drupal caching add a cache context `user.roles`:

```
$response->getCacheableMetadata()->addCacheContexts(['user.roles']);
```

Furthermore it is recommended to execute a redirect event subscriber only on a master request, this helps to prevent redirect loops:

```
public function checkFrontRedirection(RequestEvent $event) {
  if (!$event->isMainRequest()) {
    return;
  }
  ...
}
```