# Form Redirect before submit?

Tags: forms

I have a form which has 2 values prefilled (values come from a few steps the user has to take to be given the chance to get to the form I'm talking about).

My question is, how do I redirect the user back to step 1 when the form loads if the values are not present?

I have a `hook_form_alter()` and I have the logic to check whether or not the session variables are set but I cannot seem to redirect. Tried `return new RedirectResponse($url)` and `return new TrustedRedirectResponse($url)` also I've checked with the debugger to see if the returns are called and they are but the redirect is not happening and I get to the form when I should not be able to.

If it helps, it is a `group/add` form (normal entity adding).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use an Event Subscriber here. See [My First Event Subscriber](https://www.drupal.org/docs/creating-custom-modules/subscribe-to-and-dispatch-events#s-my-first-drupal-8-event-subscriber) for an example if you're unfamiliar.

In this case, you'd want to subscribe to the `Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents::REQUEST` event. For example, you might have a *getSubstribedEvents()* method that looks like:

```
public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
  // Include Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents with a use statement.
  return [
    KernelEvents::REQUEST => 'myCustomMethod',
  ];
}
```

Then define *myCustomMethod()* to check for your session variables and redirect if needed. For example:

```
public function MyCustomMethod(GetResponseEvent $event) {
  $route_name = $event->getRequest()->attributes->get('_route');
  // I'm not sure what the route name is here. (You also don't need
  // to check against a route name, thought it's probably a good idea.)
  if ($route_name == 'GROUP_ADD_ROUTE') {
    // Check whatever to see if you must redirect.
    if (myRedirectCondition()) {
      // Set these response headers so browsers don't cache the redirect.
      $response_headers = [
        'Cache-Control' => 'no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate',
      ];

      // Build your response.
      $response = new TrustedRedirectResponse(MY_REDIRECT_URL, '302', $response_headers);
      // You'll have to determine how your redirect should be cached and add
      // appropriate cache dependencies, tags, contexts, etc. There is a
      // session cache context, but I'm not familiar with that particulars of
      // exactly how it works. Alternatively, you could use \Drupal::service('page_cache_kill_switch')->trigger();
      // inside your route_name if statement. 
      $response->addCacheableDependency();
      $event->setResponse($response);
    }
  }
}
```

Related: [Disabling Page Cache for Redirect Response](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/278698/disabling-page-cache-for-redirect-response)

Comment: Thank you, explained really well and works like magic!