# Session/cookie not working for some data on certain conditions

Tags: commerce, 9, redirection

I'm trying to simply redirect to a certain page after is visited.

The scenario : the user click on a link. If the user a certain data (a store, for drupal commerce), he can go to my node. If not, redirect him to a middle page and after he submits a form, redirect him to my node.

It only works when the cache is cleared. I can't figure out why... even in private mode...

```
public static function getSubscribedEvents()
{
  $events[KernelEvents::REQUEST][] = ['redirectToStore'];
  return $events;
}


public function redirectTo(RequestEvent $event)
{
    ... 
      $path = Url::fromRoute('route.my_destination');
      $response = new RedirectResponse($path->toString());
      $url = \Drupal\Core\Url::fromRoute('<current>');
      $host = \Drupal::request()->getSchemeAndHttpHost();
      $session = \Drupal::request()->getSession();
      
      //saving the goTo works only once, then I have to clean my cache, even in private 
      user_cookie_save(['goToHome' => $host . $url->toString()]);
      //\Drupal::request()->cookies->set('goToHome', $host . $url->toString());
//        $session->set('goToHome', $host . $url->toString());
//        $_SESSION['goToHome'] = $host . $url->toString();
      $event->setResponse($response);
      //exemple : firefox 1 -> /my-target, redirect to /my-destination (url redirect in session), do stuff, redirect to /my-target
      //          firefox 2 -> /my-target, redirect to /my-destination (url in session doesn't exists), do stuff, redirect to home (instead of /my-target)
      //I have to do this to make it workss
      // \Drupal::service('page_cache_kill_switch')->trigger();
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this help? https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/295056/my-site-only-listens-to-the-event-after-i-clear-all-caches

Comment: I think it does, but the redirection is still applied when I refresh the destination...

Comment: I think this question is the same as the other.

Comment: It looks the same, but unfortunatly, even with CacheableMetadata, it's still redirect to the wrong page